# Jax-WS WSSE headers are missing in SOAP message after Hibernate, JPA upgrade

Tags: hibernate, jpa, soap, jax-ws, weblogic12c

We upgraded our application to Hibernate 4.3.10 and JPA 2.1, after that we are facing strange soap header missing issue.

Actually WSSE Soap Headers are missing in the soap message.

Setup Details

1. JDK 1.7
2. Weblogic 12.1.2

Exceptions

```
com.sun.xml.ws.fault.ServerSOAPFaultException: Client received SOAP Fault from server: Error on verifying message against security policy Error code:1000 Please see the server log to find more detail regarding exact cause of the failure.
        at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAP12Fault.getProtocolException(SOAP12Fault.java:229) ~[com.sun.xml.ws.jaxws-rt_2.2.jar:2.2.8-b13937]
        at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:125) ~[com.sun.xml.ws.jaxws-rt_2.2.jar:2.2.8-b13937]
        at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.StubHandler.readResponse(StubHandler.java:253) ~[com.sun.xml.ws.jaxws-rt_2.2.jar:2.2.8-b13937]
        at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(DatabindingImpl.java:181) ~[com.sun.xml.ws.jaxws-rt_2.2.jar:2.2.8-b13937]
        at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(DatabindingImpl.java:258) ~[com.sun.xml.ws.jaxws-rt_2.2.jar:2.2.8-b13937]
        at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:117) ~[jaxws-rt-2.2.10.jar:2.2.8-b13937]
        at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:91) ~[jaxws-rt-2.2.10.jar:2.2.8-b13937]
        at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:154) ~[jaxws-rt-2.2.10.jar:2.2.8-b13937]
```

Can you please tell me root cause of  this issue ?

Thanks,
Sampath